# How do I calculate the correlation between variables x and y in data frame data for each category of a factor cat?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a function to calculate the correlation between variables `age` and `views` in data frame `data` for each category of `gender`.

My data frame is called `tv_viewing` with 5 columns: `adhd` (numeric), `sex` (factor, boy/girl), `famsize` (factor with 4 levels (1 child, 2 child, 3 child, 4+child), `age` (numeric) and `views` (numeric, amount of watching television).

I have gotten this far:

```
partcorr <- function(tv_viewing, age, views, sex) {
  corrs <- list()
  for(i(tv_viewing[,sex])) {
    corrs[i] <- round(sex(tv_viewing[tv_viewing[,sex] == i, age], tv_viewing[tv_viewing[,sex] == i, views], method = "pearson"), digits = 2)
  }
  return()
}
```

Or, more generally,

```
partcorr <- function(data, x, y, cat) {
  corrs <- list()
  for(i in levels(data[,cat])) {
    corrs[i] <- round(cor(data[data[,cat] == i, x], data[data[,cat] == i, y], method = "pearson"), digits = 2)
  }
  return()
}
```

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we have a [mcve] please?  What does "not working" mean, specifically?  What happens if you simply `return(corrs)` rather than simply `return()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `by()` and do not need a for loop. With your data and columns, it should work like this:

```
by(tv_viewing[, c("age", "views")], tv_viewing$sex, cor)
```

Or, as I do not have access to your data, a reproducible using the `iris` data set is as follows:

```
by(iris[, 1:2], iris$Species, cor)
```

Maybe your code did not work because you did not quote your column names (`tv_viewing[, sex]` will not read your column sex, but `tv_viewing[, "sex"]` does).

EDIT: If you need the correlations in one vector, you can use this code:

```
c(by(iris[, 1:2], iris$Species, function(x) cor(x)[2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
partcorr <- function(df, 
                     col1, 
                     col2, 
                     cat, 
                     digits = 2, 
                     method = "pearson", 
                     ... ) {
  dfs <- split(df[, c(col1, col2)], df[, cat])
  sapply(dfs, function(sdf) round(cor(sdf[, col1], 
                                      sdf[, col2],
                                      method = method,
                                      ...),
                                  digits = digits))
}
```

creates for each category a subdataframe of the original `data`
with the columns given for `col1` and `col2` - in a list of data frames (`dfs`).
Then it loops over this list of data frames and calculates
the correlation with the given method between the `col1` and `col2` columns
of the subdataframes. The `...` makes that you can pass to `partcorr`
any additional arguments for the `cor` function - it will forward it to the
`cor` function.
Also the `digits` can be changed.

Comment: The (working) result: `partcorr <- function(df, 
                     col1, 
                     col2, 
                     cat, 
                     digits = 2, 
                     method = "pearson", 
                     ... ) {
  dfs <- split(df[, c(col1, col2)], df[, cat])
  sapply(dfs, function(sdf) round(cor(sdf[, col1], 
                                      sdf[, col2],
                                      method = "pearson",
                                      ...),
                                  digits = 2))
}

partcorr(tv_viewing, "age", "views", "sex")`

Comment: inside function you should give `digits = digits` - or digit give an error? Otherwise change the name to `.digits=`. Sometimes it gives error, sometimes not. - I tried - no error also with `digits=digits` in `round()`. I tried: `data(iris); partcorr(iris, 1, 2, 5, digits=3)`